# Word for one character explaining to another character some important points for benefit of the audience

Tags: terminology, literary-techniques, narration

This is not apostrophe (no, not that kind of apostrophe) or anagnorisis; this is when a character communicates a exposition on some aspect of the story's background or context (e.g. how FTL travel works; why the families are at war) ostensibly to another character (often a foreigner or recluse) but actually in place of simple omniscient narration.

I'm not criticizing the practice; I just want a word for it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is often called info-dumping or "as you know, Bob". [see also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposition_(literary_technique))

Comment: Are you thinking of "expository dialogue?" Or the broader "exposition?"

Comment: @ThePhoton you should write that as your answer, and include the link too.

Comment: @ThePhoton The link you provide also refers to it as an *idiot lecture*.

Comment: The fifth business is a related concept, though not exactly a name for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're describing is *expository dialogue*.

More colloquially, it's also called an *info dump* or "as you know, Bob" dialogue.

The last term is generally used in a critical sense, referring to dialogue in a movie or tv show that is obviously unnatural and presented only for the audience's benefit. For example:

> **Dr. Smartly**: As you know, Bob, giant robots have a universal weakness for high-fructose corn syrup, and I've been researching this in my lab. If a giant robot ever attacks Pleasantville, it's a good thing the soda pop factory is nearby...
>
> **[90 minutes later]**
>
> **Bob Dogood (our hero)**: Eat sweet justic, infernal menace!